# Springboot Cors config - MyApplication and WebConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application has ended up with two classes that both have cors configuration in them.

I presume one of them is unnecessary. Can someone explain why there is both?

MyApplication:

```
@EntityScan("com.nz.myapp")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}

public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, you shouldn't use it anymore. Just stick with an implementation of `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Comment: Great thanks. If you add that as a answer with example I will accept it. So I dont need the class WebConfig at all?

Comment: The method inside your main class does nothing, so in that way listed here it's useless. You'd have to provide it at least as a bean. Just delete it, it shouldn't be placed here anyway. And keep on with a WebConfig class, example provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, you shouldn't use it anymore. Just stick with an implementation of `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

However, later on you might set CORS configuration inside your SecurityFilterChain anyway, so the WebMvcConfigurer might more likely be used to set up resource handlers and formatters.